# Custom Display Issues List View

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good afternoon everyone, there is a problem with custom display of List View in Xamarin Forms. I need to display pictures in three columns with tiles, and under certain circumstances, stretch one of the 6 pictures into two columns and two lines, so that it looks like 4 ordinary pictures in size, while it should be streamlined with other pictures. Below is a photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7slsB.jpg)

Comment: You could set the layout of ViewCell as a Grid and set RowSpan and ColumnSpan  as 2 of the specific Image . And define a list of ImageSource in each item .

Comment: You have 9 images total or group of 9 images. Either way you have to make a grid layout or Bindable version of grid